# Tables not creating after running worker and dashborad in wso2 api manager 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Following ables not creating after running worker and dashborad in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 oracle config:

```
a.  WSO2_DASHBOARD_DB 
b.  BUSINESS_RULES_DB 
c.  WSO2_PERMISSIONS_DB 
d.  WSO2_METRICS_DB
```

what is the problem?

```
 name: WSO2_PERMISSIONS_DB
      description: The datasource used for permission feature
      jndiConfig:
        name: jdbc/PERMISSION_DB
        useJndiReference: true
      definition:
        type: RDBMS
        configuration:
          jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@apigwdb-scan.shoperation.net:1521/APIGWDB'
          username: 'WSO2_PERMISSIONS_DB'
          password: 'apigw14'
          driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
          maxPoolSize: 10
          idleTimeout: 60000
          connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
          validationTimeout: 30000
          isAutoCommit: false
          connectionInitSql: alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Comment: Are you using an external database? If so, have you pointed the relevant configs to that db in `deployment.yaml`.

Comment: Yes I am using Oracle and I have configured in  deployment.yaml, but there is no tables

Answer (score 0):

By default all these dbs have h2 configs in the `deployment.yaml`. You have to create the relevant dbs in the Oracle server and change each config for the tables to be created in those dbs.

Also, please check whether the user you have used have sufficient permission.

For more information, please check https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-42-configure-the-analytics-dashboard

Comment: I updated the question, but when the tables create? When I run dashboard it dose't create tables

Comment: They should be when Analytics is started. Do you have any data in `APIGWDB`? Did you try with a fresh db in the same database server?

Comment: I don have any data in APIGWDB, it is fresh. And I just tried to run dahsboard to be create tables